# How can I pass data to the input stream and receive data from the output stream of the child process?

Tags: c, linux, unix

A program for Linux, in the C programming language. In a program I am developing, a child process is created using the fork function, which is replaced by another program using the execl function, which I cannot change. How can I pass data from my program to the input stream and get data from the output stream of the child process?

Below is a test program that runs another test program. The parent program sends the character string to the child on standard input, the child returns it back on the standard output. I need to get an interface to programs that run interactively through the terminal. Am I doing everything right?

`./parent child test_string`

```
// parent.c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  if (argc < 3) {
    return 0;
  }
  
  char* in_str = argv[2];
  char out_str[10] = {};
  char* command = argv[1];
  int pin[2], pout[2], perr[2];
 
  pipe(pin);
  pipe(pout);
  pipe(perr);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid == 0) {
     /*Child*/
     close(pin[1]);
     dup2(pin[0], 0);
     close(pin[0]);

     close(pout[0]);
     dup2(pout[1], 1);
     close(pout[1]);

     close(perr[0]);
     dup2(perr[1], 2);
     close(perr[1]);
     execl(command, command, NULL);
     perror(command);
     exit(1);
  }
  /*Parent*/
  close(pin[0]);
  close(pout[1]);
  close(perr[1]);

  FILE *fin = fdopen(pin[1], "a");
  FILE *fout = fdopen(pout[0], "r");

  fprintf(fin, "%s\n", in_str);
  fflush(fin);
  fscanf(fout, "%9s", out_str);
  printf("%s\n", out_str);

  fclose(fin);
  close(pin[1]);
  wait(NULL);
  return 0;
}

// child.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char str[10];
  scanf("%9s", str);
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}

// child2.c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int c;
  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n') {
    putchar(c);
  }
  putchar('\n');
  return 0;
}

// build.sh
#!/bin/sh

gcc parent.c -o parent
gcc child.c -o child
gcc child2.c -o child2
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you show? Doesn't it do what you want? What does it do? What should it do? Please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: `test_string` is 11 characters long and requires a buffer of at least size 12 to hold it.  But the child has `char str[10]`.  Fix that before worrying about anything else.

Comment: It looks like it won't matter in this particular case, but writing and reading from the same child introduces the possibility of a deadlock.

Comment: You certainly should close `pin[1]` in the parent after you're done writing.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I clarified the question

Comment: @WilliamPursell the program is written just for the test, in particular the line sizes. I want to understand if I am correctly connecting to the standard input / output streams of a program from another program. I think bash does something similar when you run an interactive program from it.

Comment: @Maxim  Your program seems to work just fine except for the fact that you are trying to fit 12 characters into a 10 character buffer and allowing `scanf` to write past the bounds.  It's undefined behavior.  Just make your buffers bigger.  (And close `pin[1]` in the parent after the parent is done writing to it.)

Comment: And be aware that the deadlock issue is a real concern.  For the simple toy case you show, it's not a problem.  If you are replacing the toy sample with more realistic code, it may become a serious concern.

Comment: @Maxim If Bash did something similar then `isatty(fileno(stdin))` etc. would fail in the child program.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I limited the input and closed the stream, is this how it should be done in a real program?

Comment: @WilliamPursell how can blocking be avoided? It is supposed to work with a child thread as from a terminal. The parent thread sends a command, waits for a response, and the child thread waits for a command and sends a response.

Comment: IMO, this shouldn't be done in a real program, because deadlocks are notoriously hard to avoid.  If you find a robust solution, there's probably a nobel prize in it for you.  As long as the messages are short (eg less than 4k or so), it may not be something to worry about...(until it bites you!)

Comment: @WilliamPursell the messages are short, I am making an interface for a program that works through the terminal.